# c++ Error with literal initialize pointer with curly brace

Tags: c++, c++11, cmake

I'm learning new of c++.
In my text book, there is very simple example this.

```
int* ip = nullptr; // (ok)
int* ip1{}; // (error)
int* ip2{nullptr}; // (error)

unique_ptr<double> dp{new double}; // (error)
```

But I got this error with build it.

```
/Users/bsdo/projects/CPlus/modernbook/include/basis.cpp:81:30: error: expected ';' at end of declaration
    unique_ptr<double> dp{new double};
                         ^
                         ;
In file included from     /Users/bsdo/projects/CPlus/modernbook/main.cpp:2:
/Users/bsdo/projects/CPlus/modernbook/include/basis.cpp:81:30: error: expected ';' at end of declaration
    unique_ptr<double> dp{new double};
                         ^
                         ;
/Users/bsdo/projects/CPlus/modernbook/main.cpp:10:13: error: expected ';' at end of declaration
int* ip1{nullptr};
        ^
        ;
```

Why only curly brace literal throw error??

My env is Mac book pro 2015, Cmake-3.11, Apple LLVM version 9.1.0 (clang-902.0.39.1).

Comment: Mandatory question... did you enable C++11 when building?

Comment: What a shame.. I reset my cmakelist settings. and fix it! Thanks @StoryTeller

Comment: your question reads as if the text book example claims that all but the first line should result in an error, but I guess the comments are yours and not from the book

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make cmake compile c++11..

Configuration is write this line in CmakeLists.txt

```
set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
```